# Bug in hindent (5.3.4) with Haskell choice operator?

Tags: haskell

Working through Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell, second edition, I have the following piece of code:

```
int :: Parser Int
int =
  do char '-'
     n <- nat
     return (-n)
     <|> nat
```

The formatting above is the result of applying hindent 5.3.4 to the piece of code.

As far as I know, that code is equivalent to:

```
int :: Parser Int
int =
  (do char '-'
      n <- nat
      return (-n)) <|>
  nat
```

In fact, the latter formatting is the result of the same hindent, and I think it is correct.

Isn't the former formatting, if not incorrect, at least confusing? Is that a bug in hindent? Worth reporting at https://github.com/mihaimaruseac/hindent/issues, maybe?

By the way, the formatting in the book is:

```
int :: Parser Int
int = do char '-'
         n <- nat
         return (-n)
      <|> nat
```

Comment: It might be confusing, but maybe it's not incorrect? Personally, I tend to avoid that style, since I dislike using inline operators like `<|>` between multi-line expressions. In the case above I'd rather write `int = negative <|> nat` and then `where negative = do ...` but that not something a formatter can write on its own.

Comment: After more investigations with further examples from the same chapter in the book, my conclusion is that for such examples, minor changes in indentation can drastically change the meaning of an expression. So I will definitely  go for parentheses in such cases. @chi's suggestion is good too, at the cost of introducing not strictly necessary names.

Comment: That looks worth reporting to hindent. The alignment suggests that hindent is considering that last line as part of the block, which is wrong. The resulting code is correct by accident; it's likely that the indentation is not the intended one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like a bug, I have posted [an issue](https://github.com/mihaimaruseac/hindent/issues/676).